# Firefox is autofilling '{2}' in a textbox. Firefox version is 31.1.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

```html
<Common:TextBox ID="tbxUsername" runat="server" CssClass="usrnm_id usrValidation" maxlength="50" ValidationGroup="valGrpUserName"/>
```

we have a textbox which is used for new username for creation of a new account. But when user lands on the page the username autofills with '{2}'. I have used autocomplete = "off" but no use.Firefox version is 31.1.1.

HTML

Comment: I can't able to add screenshot here, as i dont have reputation minimum 10.

Comment: Sorry, Firefox will not suddenly start to fill in text in input fields. More likely your html markup you generate contains that text. _Did you check that_?

Comment: yes i checked it was just normal HTML code. nothing else unusual.

Comment: and below code is there in aspx. <Common:TextBox ID="tbxUsername" runat="server" CssClass="usrnm_id usrValidation" maxlength="50" ValidationGroup="valGrpUserName"/>

Comment: Sorry, please stop adding details in comments. There is an `edit` button below the question.

Comment: And I somehow  doubt that this _really_ is the markup inside the browser: `name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$_$ctl00$_$usrSecurityUsername$_$tbxUsername"`. If so then that strange platform creates even more horrible code than I imagined.

Comment: actually that code i got it from 'inspect element with Firebug'

Comment: If so, then I'd say good luck. To me such created markup crap looks impossible to debug. Sorry. Never understood why people use that platform.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to rant. But really, look at it...

Comment: its ok, i was waiting for anyone to answer how to clear textbox without any default values when landing on resetpassword page

Comment: @arkascha Sorry for going a bit OT, but. The fact that you don't like it doesn't make it horrible. It shows exactly where the element is in the tree and makes the control names unique in a reasonable way. It's not like you have to ever write those by hand. There aren't many better solutions for this, or do you want to guess which element is txtbox387459, or magically create unique names for dynamically created elements?